# Python - Is there a more elegant way to write this IF statement which contains multiple OR

Tags: python

I have this IF, OR statement:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4

if a == 5 or b == 5 or c == 5 or d == 5:
    # do something
else:
    # do something different
```

I was wondering if this is the best way to write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use the `element in list` syntax. Also, there's no need to use an `if else` statement if you only want to print `true` or `false`. You could just print the boolean directly:

```
print(5 in [a, b, c, d])
# False
```

If you want a lowercase string:

```
print(str(5 in [a, b, c, d]).lower())
# "false"
```

Finally, if you often need this test, you could pack the values into a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
all_values = set([a, b, c, d])
```

You'll invest some time to create the set, but the query `5 in all_values` should become faster, especially if there are many variables.

Comment: For premature optimization, use a `set` instead of `list`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Just in case it wasn't 100% sarcasm, I added a note about sets.

Comment: Whats the advantage of using a `set` over a `list`, is it just faster?

Comment: @Lewis909 With many variables (let's say 1000), it should be much faster, yes. Otherwise, as mentioned by Chris_Rands, it would be premature optimization.

Answer (score 4):

This would be preferable in my eyes.

```
if any(x==5 for x in (a, b, c, d)):
   ...
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

Similarly if you want to do multiple `and` checks you can use `all()` with the same syntax.

Finally, for your special case, and since the only thing you want to do is a membership test I would go with the answer posted by @Eric. My approach is more generic.

Comment: I prefer this one for readability over `5 in [...` solutions. It also generalizes nicely for any logical-valued expression using `x`, not just equality.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, as someone learning Python its useful to see the different solutions to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `if 5 in [a, b, c,d]:`

In case if you want to check equality of variables with different number `any()` is a safe bet

`if any([a == 1, b == 2, c == 3, d == 4]):`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps by just using `in`:

```
if 5 in (a,b,c,d):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

or just

```
print(5 in (a,b,c,d))
```

Comment: I was using `print` as an example of the if statement doing something, I have edited the question to reflect this.